# Python - Import class function/method from main to use in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

I have two files - main.py and uploadfile.py. Main.py (GUI) takes user input, and provides this to uploadfile.py to process. I have an entry `from uploadfile import Uploader` in main that allows main to talk to uploadfile.

I need to have error handling, and I need to call the `errorfunc` residing in main.py from uploadfile.py if there is an error (this is to display an alert window with the error in question).

main.py

```
class ErrorHandling (QDialog):
   def __init__(self, ErrorObject):
   QMessageBox.__init__(self)

   def errorfunction(self):
       print("error!")
```

uploadfile.py

```
class Uploder:
      def __init__(self):

      def uploadfile(self, item1frommain, item2frommain)
          for Files in self.Filestoupload:
              try:
                 self.FileCopy(FilePaths, Metadata)
              except Exception as errno:
                 errorfunction(errno) #<--- placeholder as unsure how to achieve
```

Apologies if this code is incomplete, main and uploadfile are rather large to post in entirety. I would be appreciative of just knowing the way in which I would do this (call a class method/function that is in main). Note, trying `from main import ErrorHandling` causes main to no longer run with the error `cannot import name Uploader from uploadfile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding any import statements(of main.py) at the top of uploader.py will cause circular import errors. Two ways to remedy it.

1. Move `ErrorHandling` to a new utils.py module
2. Write the import statement inside `except` clause

```
try:
  self.FileCopy(FilePaths, Metadata)          
except Exception as errno:
  from main import ErrorHandling
  ErrorHandling(errno)
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. Is this an acceptable way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could hand over the needed class in the constructor like

```
class Uploder:
     def __init__(self, errorhandler):
         self.errorhandler = errorhandler()

     def uploadfile(self, item1frommain, item2frommain):
         ...
         self.errorhandler.errorfunction(errno)
```

and in `main.py`

```
Uploader(ErrorHandling)
```

remark: Uploader would be the correct spelling

Comment: Thank you. When you say in `main.py` to add `Uploader(ErrorHandling)` where would that go?

Comment: It would replace your normal call to `Uploader`.